# Is there a way to get the content-length (response header) in apache logs?

Tags: apache, authentication, http-headers

I would like Apache to show the response header length (here 90).
Instead it shows some 'weird' values that are also client-dependent.

**tail /var/log/apache2/access.log**

```
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [16/Oct/2021:11:07:44 +0000] "POST /api/user HTTP/1.1" 200 796 "https://yy/login/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36 OPR/79.0.4143.72"
```

**Inspect Elements**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 16 Oct 2021 11:07:44 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 90
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: By "some 'weird' values", are you referring to the `796` in the log?

Comment: Yes. And this value depends on the client browser. That is why I would like to have ‘90´ in the Apache log (for subsequent fail2ban actions).

Comment: Found some more info there. Indeed the values as reported by Apache (Ubuntu) are misleading : https://www.trustwave.com/en-us/resources/blogs/spiderlabs-blog/how-much-data-apache-ubuntu-and-the-lies-of-the-logs/ . I guess to change the log format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution :

in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, the LogFormat directives have to be changed as follows: **%b** instead of %O.

And now the `access.log` reports 90 as expected.

This is also discussed here (comment by
Jeff Pucket): https://askubuntu.com/questions/264042/what-is-the-default-apache2-log-format-and-where-is-defined-such-default and it looks like this is Ubuntu specific.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Curious, this was apparently [changed in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264042/what-is-the-default-apache2-log-format-and-where-is-defined-such-default#comment1213597_656843) - I wonder why they overrode the Apache defaults, rather than creating an additional log format? This feels like it goes against best practice as it would seem to be a _breaking_ change?